# Transaction fee, gasLimit and usedGas in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I am reading about Gas in Ethereum and how it is used to control executions. There are a few things not clear to me:

TransactionFee = GasLimit * GasPrice (both specified by the account?)

As I have understood, when a transaction is processed, and after mining, this fee goes to the miner. On the other hand, to the EOA it is removed from the balance the amount of GasUsed*GasPrice and the difference GasLimit - GasUsed is returned also to the EOA (if transaction valid). 
My questions are:

1. There is no gas Field in an Account as specified in the paper of Gavin Wood. How is the GasLimit - GasUsed returned to the account? Is it converted in Wei?
2. In the book 'Mastering Ethereum' of  Andreas M. Antonopoulos and Gavin Wood there is a phrase

> "You are only billed for gas actually consumed by your transaction,
>   but you have to have enough balance for the maximum amount you are
>   willing to pay before you send your transaction"

while in the paper for gasLimit field it is said

> "This is paid up-front, before any computation is done and may not be
>   increased"

What is the Account paying for? gasLimit or consumedGas?

3. If it is paying for consumedGas, than shouldnt the miner be payed for consumedGas instead of transactionFee since the 'money' extracted from the sender goes to the miner. 
   If it is the TransactionFee, the miner it is being paid the consumedGas of sender + the difference in gas but this difference is also being returned to the account?! Its like Ethereum uses twice the same difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

- The transaction signer defines a *gas limit* and a *gas price*.
- When processing the transaction that amount (*gas limit* * *gas price*) is deducted from the transaction sender's account.
- At the end of the transaction, the amount of gas used is *gas used*. The sender's account is credited for what wasn't used. That amount is (*gas limit* - *gas used*) * *gas price*.

So the net result is that *gas used* * *gas price* has been deducted from the sender's account, and this is the amount that is credited to the miner as part of their reward. Although technically there's a deduction and then a refund (so that balances are right during the transaction processing), it's usually simpler to think of it as just "you pay for the gas you use." I think this is why you see it described different ways in different places.

To answer your individual questions:

1. It's multiplied by the gas price. That turns it into wei.
2. The account ultimately pays for just consumed gas.
3. Yes, the miner only gets paid for the consumed gas.